# If a function $f$ is invertible can I say that $f^{-1}$ is also one to one and onto?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If we have a function $f$ that is both one-to-one and onto (so it's invertible). Its inverse function $f^{-1}$ is also one-to-one and onto? If this is not true can someone  please explain it to me or give me a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the inverse is also 1-1 and onto.  Note that the inverse also has an inverse, so it must also be 1-1 and onto since having an inverse is actually equivalent to being 1-1 and onto.